# Completion heads engraver does not draw stems

Tags: lilypond

I am using completion heads engraver and completion rest engraver as follows:

```
\new StaffGroup <<                                                                  
  \override StaffGroup.SystemStartBracket.stencil = ##f                             
  \new Staff \with {                                                                
    \remove "Note_heads_engraver"                                                   
    \consists "Completion_heads_engraver"                                           
    \remove "Rest_engraver"                                                         
    \consists "Completion_rest_engraver"                                            
  } \relative {                                                                     
    g'8 ais8 dis2                                                                   
  }                                                                                 
>>
```

This produces the following:

[image]

For some reason the stem of the tied note is not drawn. How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that usually NoteHeads are not created on Staff level, but on Voice level. And this has a good reason: Note head spacing needs to take into account voice information, and Beaming should happen only within one voice. We could just move everything from Voice to Staff

```
\new StaffGroup <<                                                                  
  \override StaffGroup.SystemStartBracket.stencil = ##f                             
  \new Staff \with {                                                                
    \remove "Note_heads_engraver"                                                   
    \consists "Completion_heads_engraver"                                           
    \remove "Rest_engraver"                                                         
    \consists "Completion_rest_engraver"
  } \relative {                      
    \time 2/4
    g'8 ais8 dis2                                                                   
  }                                                                                 
>>

\layout {
  \context {
    \Voice
    \remove Stem_engraver
    \remove Beam_engraver
    \remove Note_heads_engraver
    \remove Rest_engraver
    \remove Auto_beam_engraver
  }
  \context {
    \Staff
    \consists Stem_engraver
    \consists Beam_engraver
    \consists Note_heads_engraver
    \consists Rest_engraver
    \consists Auto_beam_engraver
  }
}
```

but you need to be aware that this would create the effect of having only a single voice. Much better would be to do this:

```
\layout {
  \context {
    \Voice
    \name CompletionVoice
    \alias Voice
    \remove "Note_heads_engraver"                                                   
    \consists "Completion_heads_engraver"                                           
    \remove "Rest_engraver"                                                         
    \consists "Completion_rest_engraver" 
  }
  \context {
    \Staff
    \accepts CompletionVoice
  }
}
                        
\new Staff \with {
  \defaultchild CompletionVoice
} \relative {  
  \time 2/4
  g'8 ais8 dis2                                                                   
}

\new Staff \with {
  \defaultchild CompletionVoice
} \relative {  
  \time 2/4
  <<
    {
      g'8 ais8 dis2 
    } \\
    {
      e,8 fis2 gis8
    }
  >>
}
```

which defines a new voice-style context CompletionVoice, which contains the necessary changes. Then we can already do `\new CompletionVoice ...`, and by setting the default child context of a staff from Voice to CompletionVoice we can set this as default behaviour for a whole Staff.

Comment: At this time my \layout block is inside \score. Shall I just replace it ? I got this: warning: cannot create default child context: CompletionVoice

Comment: @kargirwar It should not matter whether you specify this in a global layout or in a score layout (although if you need this more often it would make sense to have this in global layout that can be included on toplevel). The warning message you got should happen if you omit that `\layout { \context { \Voice \name CompletionVoice ... } }` stuff. Maybe you could produce a small failing piece of code so I can check if there is any mistake?

Comment: @kargirwar And if you need this for only a single voice you can simply do `\new Staff \new Voice \with { ... } ...`.

Comment: I have just this inside \score <<>>:  \new Staff \with {                                                         
        \defaultchild CompletionVoice                                            
      } \relative {                                                              
        g'8 ais8 dis2                                                            
      }  and the \layout as above and \midi{}

Comment: @kargirwar The warning you get comes from the midi output. The reason is that we define a new engraver group, but not a new performer group, so the performer group Staff cannot add the default child performer group CompletionVoice. Simply add a score or global midi block containing `\midi {
  \context {
    \Voice
    \name CompletionVoice
    \alias Voice
  }
  \context {
    \Staff
    \accepts CompletionVoice
  }
}` and it should be fine.

Comment: This works as expected untill I add an \addlyrics block. Then it starts generating wrong output. Any ideas?

Comment: @kargirwar Hm, the problem here is that `\addlyrics` appears to add a voice context. So instead of using `\addlyrics` you’d need to do `<< \new Staff \new CompletionVoice = "voiceID" ... \new Lyrics \lyricsto "voiceID" ... >>`.